# MSSQL to MySQL API conversion layer

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, protocols

I'm looking for a program that can emulate, impersonate a Microsoft SQL server and convert and write the queries to a MySQL database. Thus allowing me to configure client applications developed for SQL Server database systems only, to connect to the emulator and thus writing and reading the MySQL based records.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is why people develop data access layers, so the database can be switched out.  Good luck with this... you're better off just changing the SQL in the application to MySQL syntax.

Comment: forget it: emulating SQL Server with MySQL is like painting the Sistine Chapel in morse code

Comment: What would be the goal of this?  If you write your SQL in a commonly support ANSI subset, you'll be 90% of the way there (plus testing, the other 90%).  I'm not seeing the business justification for this - database platforms have limited portability, if you choose one based on features, you should expect to use those features.  If you wanted a generic database platform in the first place, you would "just" use an ORM and sacrifice database power and performance and use its generated code.

Answer (score 2):

In all but entirely trivial cases this is not at all easy, and in general is not practical. The only thing that will impersonate a Microsoft SQL Server is SQL Server. Some of the facilities of MSSQL are not available on MySQL (and vice versa).

If you can't redo the client application to use database abstraction, your best bet is to install SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks,
Several custom applications were developed by a third party for our company. The host IP, instance, database etc. configurations were all hard coded, YES?. Now I'm unable (unless I keep the hostname and setup exactly the same) to retire the DB host and migrate all the databases to the new host. Maybe I could use some sort of editor, perhaps a Hex editor to amend the applications, don't know how to do this yet!

Comment: Hardcoded DB ip? That is awful, did you pay them?! Hardcoded database type is not unusual, but address is.
You could put a proxy to redirect the IP, but you wont be able to change the type. I wouldn't recomend using a hex editor on an application that is used in your company (not that I haven't done it). Best option would be to get back to the company who sold you the applications and ask for them to fix the hardcode, which I would consider a fault.

Answer (score 2):

An actual Microsoft SQL Server will impersonate it self perfectly. Just think of this MSSQL Server as your "intermediate layer", and then write another app that moves or updates the data you need into or from a separate MySQL database.

That's why there is no purpose to such an expensive proxy layer, because, you can just use the actual DB Engine required by the app, and then connect to that Engine from another app to do whatever you need to do.

Why is it so expensive? Think of the extent of the different SQL dialects, the communication protocols, and the continuous updates that they both receive by huge development teams. The developers of MSSQL and MySQL are working every day to make such a proxy server harder to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the licencing rules would be, or the legal implications - but how about you write one?
It's likely that you aren't the only person who would want one, but I'm not aware that one exists.

I suspect MS have put a considerable investment into making features that other database engines would struggle to implement (intentionally so) so for things beyond the vanilla, it would probably be quite tricky.

That said, since there express versions of SQL Server available (size limited, but fine for small databases), Any reason you can't use that?

Comment: Thanks Ragster,
We have quite a large fleet of vehicles and their info and GEO data are all stored in the database. The database file size has, over the years, grown to just over 90GB. I have considered developing my own utility, but aren't sure if this is legal, possible or viable, in terms of performance, R&D time spent etc. I won't give up though, I'm sure many will benefit from such a utility, especially Linux based server systems. Maybe I can give something back to the Open Source Community. Best Regards.

Comment: Gosh. Ok, Given that background, I have to say, your best long-term option is almost definately, re-write the application. Yes, it will cost, and you'll have to deal with the loss of the original investment, but not having the flexibility you need, or the proper ownership of yoru code will cost you again and again. The sooner you pay the exit fee and get it done properly, the better.
For your own benefit, I really would advise you to get the system re-done.